# Geocode two or more addresses

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm interested in geocode addresses client-side https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client I found a piece of code in this website http://opengeocode.org/tutorials/googlemap/googlemaps_6.php#example_6 and I tried to modify in order to achieve my aim. The problem is that I only get the first address. What's wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Map Template with Geocoded Address</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>    <!-- Google Maps API -->
    <script>
    var map;    // Google map object

    // Initialize and display a google map
    function Init()
    {
        // Create a Google coordinate object for where to initially center the map
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 38.8951, -77.0367 );   // Washington, DC

        // Map options for how to display the Google map
        var mapOptions = { zoom: 12, center: latlng  };

        // Show the Google map in the div with the attribute id 'map-canvas'.
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    }

    // Update the Google map for the user's inputted address
    function UpdateMap( )
    {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();    // instantiate a geocoder object
        var destinationGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 

        // Get the user's inputted address
        var address = document.getElementById( "address" ).value;
        var destination = document.getElementById( "destination" ).value;

        // Make asynchronous call to Google geocoding API
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            var addr_type = results[0].types[0];    // type of address inputted that was geocoded
            if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) 
                ShowLocation( results[0].geometry.location, address, addr_type );
            else     
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);        
        });

        destinationGeocoder.geocode( { 'destination': destination }, function(results, status) {
            var addr_type = results[0].types[0];    // type of address inputted that was geocoded
            if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) 
                ShowLocation( results[0].geometry.location, destination, addr_type );
            else     
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);        
        });
    }

    // Show the location (address) on the map.
    function ShowLocation( latlng, add, addr_type )
    {
        // Center the map at the specified location
        map.setCenter( latlng );

        // Set the zoom level according to the address level of detail the user specified
        var zoom = 12;
        switch ( addr_type )
        {
        case "administrative_area_level_1"  : zoom = 6; break;      // user specified a state
        case "locality"                     : zoom = 10; break;     // user specified a city/town
        case "street_address"               : zoom = 15; break;     // user specified a street address
        }
        map.setZoom( zoom );

        // Place a Google Marker at the same location as the map center 
        // When you hover over the marker, it will display the title
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker( { 
            position: latlng,     
            map: map,      
            title: address
        });

        // Create an InfoWindow for the marker
        var contentString = "" + address + "";  // HTML text to display in the InfoWindow
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { content: contentString } );

        // Set event to display the InfoWindow anchored to the marker when the marker is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() { infowindow.open( map, marker ); });
    }

    // Call the method 'Init()' to display the google map when the web page is displayed ( load event )
    google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', Init );

    </script>
    <style>
    /* style settings for Google map */
    #map-canvas
    {
        width : 500px;  /* map width */
        height: 500px;  /* map height */
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body> 
    <!-- Dislay Google map here -->
    <div id='map-canvas' ></div><br/>
    <div>
        <label for="address"> Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="address"/>
        <label for="destination"> Destination:</label>
        <input type="text" id="destination"/>
        <button onclick="UpdateMap()">Locate</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Moreover: if I swap the two geocode function I don't get any result, I can't explain why

Comment: How do you make your code exhibit the issue?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.  I get two javascript errors with the code as posted `Uncaught InvalidValueError: unknown property destination` and `Uncaught InvalidValueError: setTitle: not a string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a  mistake  in your code in the  destinationGeocoder you must use `address` instead of `destination`  the geocode property is always `address`

```
 destinationGeocoder.geocode( { 'address': destination }, function(results, status) {
        var addr_type = results[0].types[0];    // type of address inputted that was geocoded
        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) 
            ShowLocation( results[0].geometry.location, destination, addr_type );
        else     
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);        
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I get two javascript errors with the code as posted.

- `Uncaught InvalidValueError: unknown property destination`.
  This is incorrect:

  ```
  destinationGeocoder.geocode({
     'destination': destination
  },
  ```

should be (there is no `destination` option for the [GeocoderRequest object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest):

```
    destinationGeocoder.geocode({
       'address': destination
    },
```

If I fix this, I get both markers.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jywrp8nw/)

- Uncaught InvalidValueError: setTitle: not a string

This one is because this is incorrect:

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latlng,
       map: map,
       title: address
   });
```

There is no variable address in the `ShowLocation` function, should be:

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latlng,
       map: map,
       title: add
   });
```

[fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jywrp8nw/1/)